# регулярное выражение: поиск нескольких подстрок в строке

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти записи в БД где поле `text` содержит одну или несколько искомых строк, причем последовательность строк может быть разная, главное чтобы все искомые подстроки присутствовали в строке

Например: мы ищем все записи, где в поле `text` присутствуют подстроки '*elit*', '*dolor*', '*sit*', и должны найти строку содержимое поле `text` которой равно '*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.*'

REGEXP 'elit|dolor|sit' не годиться, т.к. вернет нам строки в поле `text` которых присутствует хотя бы одна из этих подстрок.

Как нужно изменить регулярку?

Comment: А нужны именно регулярки ? если подстроки точно заданы, может проще `like '%строка1%' or like '%строка2%' or ... `

Comment: Подстрок несколько будет, LIKE ищет только в той последовательности, в какой указаны подстроки. Например LIKE '%ул.%Востания%' не найдет строку где есть ' Востания ул. '

Comment: Я имел ввиду `like '%ул.%' or like '%Восстания%'`. Но похоже вам это не подойдет, вы видимо хотите что бы между 'ул' и 'восстания' еще и других строк не было. тогда только жуткий регексп `/(ул.|Восстания).?(ул.|Восстания)/` И если слов больше то ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это будет очень нетривиальный регексп, особенно если последовательность подстрок может быть любая, плюс не факт что энжин субд его поймет, плюс скорее всего производительность будет чуть меньше чем нулевая. Не проще ли сделать несколько сравнений с `AND`? Или использовать тогда уж специально предназначенные для полнотекстового поиска вещи типа [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Comment: Да, пора уже освоить Sphinx!